# French localization file doesn't seem to be working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, localization

I have a localization file that I created that works fine, I called it:

```
Labels.resx
```

Now in my global.asax.cs, if a particular querystring value is present, I change the language to french:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-CA");
```

I created a new resource file:

```
Labels.fr-CA.resx
```

I just put a single entry in the new french local file to test it, now when the controller action executes, while debugging I can see in the immediate window that the culture has changed correctly, but my text label is not in french.

What could the issue be?

The properties for my Labels.fr-CA.resx file are exactly like my Labels.resx file:

- embedded resource
- PublicResXFileCodeGenerator
- (same namespace)

Also, if the given key isn't found, does it automatically lookup the value in the Strings.resx key as a fallback or does it cause an exception?

Comment: Where is this RESX file located? In which folder? Also how are you using the values in your code?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov In my razor views like: ` @MyResources.Labels.HEADER_TEXT`  They are in my class library project in a folder /Localization'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add the folowing line to global.ajax.cs:
`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-CA");`